# php insert using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Is it possible to insert more than 30 fields at a time in MySQL database? Is there any syntax or insert limit because of which I cannot insert successfully?

Here is my php mysql insert code.

```
<?php
$conn=connect();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if($conn)
{
$email=$_SESSION['email_id'];
$user=$_SESSION['username'];
    $query1=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into client_details values(
                         NULL,
                        '$email',
                        '$user'
                        '$no_panel',
                        '$no_inverter',
                        '$make_of_panel',
                        '$make_of_inverter',
                        '$make_of_dcdb',
                        '$make_of_acdb',
                        '$panel_capacity',
                        '$inverter_capacity',
                        '$dcdb_spd_capacity',
                        '$dcdb_mcb_capacity',
                        '$acdb_spd_capacity',
                        '$acdb_mcb_capacity',
                        '$type_earth',
                        '$string1_current',
                        '$string2_current',
                        '$string1_voltage',
                        '$string2_voltage',
                        '$p_n_voltage',
                        '$p_p_voltage',
                        '$p_e_voltage',
                        '$n_e_voltage',
                        '$dc_cable_1',
                        '$dc_cable_2',
                        '$ac_cable_1',
                        '$ac_cable_2',  
                        '$ac_cable_3',  
                        '$ac_cable_4',
                        '$ac_cable_5',
                        '$earthing_cable_used',
                        '$lightning_arrestor_make',
                        '$wind_speed_limit')");
         if($query1)
          {
           echo '<br><p style="color:green;">Successfully Entered</p>  <br>';
        }


    }
    else
    {
        echo '<br><span style="color:red;">Try again</span><br>';
    }
}

     else
     {
      echo '<span style="color:red;">Connection Failed</span>';
      }
  }
```

Comment: There is no such limit, the cause of your problem should be found elsewhere.

Comment: you can not insert `null` as id! Also a comma is missing after `'$user'´

Comment: There could be a limit on your MySQL installation, but not one inherently with PHP. More information is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html. I'd really really recommend binding your variables, because one bad variable here will break your whole query.

Comment: You case use `DEFAULT` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: @Jens You can if the column is set to auto-increment and not null: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: The value of one of your fields might contain a quote: `'`, which would make the query invalid. Please bind your variables, like @aynber suggested.